# Ubuntu 16.04 Display Problem

Tags: display, 16.04, amd-graphics

I upgraded 15.10 to 16.04 without seeing the warnings that AMD Proprietary drivers will no longer work.  The upgrade proceeded normally, however, my screen is at 1400 X 1050 (4:3) and the display settings have no other options, so everything is spread out and videos won't play.  Is there a way to fix the installed driver, or install another?  My graphics is Radeon HD 6530D.
Additional Information:  When I checked settings details, it says the graphics is Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 128 bits).  This doesn't seem right.
More info:  Also, there is no /etc/X11/xorg.conf file.  Should there be?